# Explain size (capacity) of lists in python

Tags: python, list

Please explain how python decides on the size or capacity of lists, when they're created (with list(), using list comprehension ...),and when they're modified.

I have these questions because i tried the following little program and got a bit confused and curious by the results. (Maybe my formulas are wrong!)

```py
from sys import getsizeof

empty_list = []
list_base_size = getsizeof(empty_list)
print(f"{list_base_size = } bytes.")

print()

list_manually = [
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
    ]
list_manually_size = getsizeof(list_manually)
list_manually_capacity = (list_manually_size - list_base_size) // 8
print(f"{list_manually_size = } bytes.")
print(f"{list_manually_capacity = } elemnts.")

print()

list_constructor = list(range(20))
list_constructor_size = getsizeof(list_constructor)
list_constructor_capacity = (list_constructor_size - list_base_size) // 8
# list capacity should also be equal to :
# from cpython
# new_allocated = (size_t)newsize + (newsize >> 3) + (newsize < 9 ? 3 : 6);
print(f"{list_constructor_size = } bytes.")
print(f"{list_constructor_capacity = } elemnts.")

print()

list_comprehension = [i for i in range(20)]
list_comprehension_size = getsizeof(list_comprehension)
list_comprehension_capacity = (list_comprehension_size - list_base_size) // 8
print(f"{list_comprehension_size = } bytes.")
print(f"{list_comprehension_capacity = } elemnts.")
```

Output

```
ist_base_size = 56 bytes.

list_manually_size = 216 bytes.
list_manually_capacity = 20 elemnts.     

list_constructor_size = 216 bytes.       
list_constructor_capacity = 20 elemnts.  

list_comprehension_size = 248 bytes.     
list_comprehension_capacity = 24 elemnts.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a list from anything whose length is known (i.e. you can call `len` on it) the list will be initialized to the exact correct size. A comprehension size isn't known so the list grows in capacity every time the existing capacity gets filled. It grows by more than 1 to be efficient.

Comment: So can we say that a list created from anything whose length is know is like a mutable tuple, at least until you append to it or something?

Comment: @NaughtyConstrictor interesting way to put it, but I think it's accurate.

Comment: thanks! By the way, is the formula i gave for the new capacity used only when doing an append or extend (or something equivalent to list), so for the list comprehension we started with size 0, added an element so we calculate the new capacity which should 4 i believe and when we hit 5 elements we calculate the new capacity again until we reached 24 at the end, is that how it works?

Comment: @NaughtyConstrictor I haven't looked at the CPython source so I can't say. It's subject to change at any time anyway.

Comment: Hi, sorry it's me again. When you said anything whose length is know i.e you can call len on it, well if i'm creating a list comprehension from another list for example then its length is know right? Or is it because what we're looping through is actually an iterator and not the list? Even if that's the case i believe the length can be checked (if possible) before calling __iter__, but maybe it's not worth it.

Comment: @NaughtyConstrictor determining the length of a comprehension expression seems like a hard problem in the general case, certainly more trouble than the saving of a tiny bit of overhead. You can always use the comprehension to make a temporary list then make a copy, the copy won't have the overhead.